# How to pass an argument into a non-static method?

Tags: java, eclipse

so I want to call this method from another class which is a non-static method that requires an argument of a string. However when I try to enter an argument into the parameter for the book.borrow method it says that I "cannot make a static reference to a non-static method". What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibrarySystem{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        book book1 = new book("Divergent", "Veronica Roth", "B001", null);
        book book2 = new book("Green Eggs and Ham", "Dr Seuss", "B002", null);
        System.out.printf("%s\n", book1.title.toString()+ " " + (book1.bookID.toString()));
        System.out.printf("%s\n", book2.title.toString()+ " "  + (book2.bookID.toString()));

        Scanner students = new Scanner(System.in);
        String student  = String.valueOf(students);
        book.borrow(student);
    }
}
```

Underneath has the method that I want to call

```
public boolean borrow(String borrowerID) {
    if (bookID != null) {
        this.borrowerID = borrowerID;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: call the method on a instance of book, so instead of `book.borrow(student)` use `book1.borrow(student)`

Comment: you dont have the `book` object

Comment: Oh my lord. Thank you so much, I actually had no idea, I thought I had  to call the method from the book class so I put book instead....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
book.borrow(student);
```

above code snippet would have been valid if `borrow` method was a `static` method.

Since its `not-static`, you can only call it on an `instance` of `book` class.

```
book1.borrow(student);
```

Answer (score 0):

If a method is not declared static, the method **must** be called on an instance of the object, not a static reference. You must initialize the class containing the method, then run `borrow()`.